# Why no rotate property in matrix 2d?

Tags: algorithms

Why no rotate property in matrix 2D ?
we know the short hand code in matrix 2D
transform:matrix(a,b,c,d,x,y)
a=scale X
b=Skew y
c=skew X
d=scale Y

x=translate X
y=translate Y

why developers didn't create extra place for rotation 2D?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking here. Some context is missing. Also, it sounds a bit like a rant.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 x 2 portion of the matrix ($a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$) can represent rotation as well as scaling and skewing. I'd have to see the code to be sure, but if the angle is $\theta$, you would probably set $a$ and $d$ to $cos(\theta)$, $b$ to $-sin(\theta)$ and $c$ to $sin(\theta)$. Put another way, rotation can be constructed as a combination of scaling and skewing.